# Attempted to load class "Formatter" from namespace "FormatterBundle\Validator\Constraints" in AbstractLoader.php line 64

Tags: symfony

I want to use sonatanews bundle. While I run post create error showing -

Attempted to load class "Formatter" from namespace "Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Sonata\FormatterBundle\Validator\Constraints" in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Loader\AbstractLoader.php line 64. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

Please any one help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify your `composer.json` file that way

```
"sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "dev-master",
```

(in the original file should be: `"sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "~2.3",`)

Then you have to run update in order to make this change "persistent": `composer update`

Comment: Thanks it resolved but another error showing below -                             ConfigManagerException: The CKEditor config "news" does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I solved it by adding in config.yml

```
ivory_ck_editor:
    default_config: default
    configs:

        news:
            toolbar:      standard
```

Comment: Run into this with SonataNews bundle and added above config. I had to remove the default_config option however.